# UIPasteboard: NSString refuses to copy to clipboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipasteboard

I have the following code to shorten a URL using the bit.ly API.

```
NSString *shortenedURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login=%@&apikey=%@&longUrl=%@&format=txt", login, key, self.link.text]] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

I also have the following code to copy the shortened URL to the pasteboard:

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
pasteboard.string = shortenedURL;
```

However, this does not work. In the output log, this is what is displayed:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPasteboard setString:]: Argument is not an object of type NSString [(null)]'
```

So if the argument isn't an object, what is it? I tried assuming it was a URL with this:

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
pasteboard.URL = shortenedURL;
```

The same type of error is produced, only saying that the argument is not an `NSURL` object, instead of the previous error saying the argument is not an `NSString` object.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPasteboard setURL:]: Argument is not an object of type NSURL [(null)]'
```

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: `shortenedURL` is `nil`. This problem has nothing to do with the pasteboard. Split up that first line into several so you can debug the problem, Also, make use of the `error` parameter instead of passing `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the `string` property on the `UIPasteboard` object is not actually a direct reference to a string, but an interface with getters and setters for an Objective-C array of the given type you care about.

Swift provides optionals, but unfortunately `UIPasteboard` is Objective-C under the hood, which doesn't really support optionals well.  This is one of those cases.

If you assign `nil` (null) to the `string` property, execution will wrap your null in square brackets as an array `[(null)]` then attempt to add it to empty array of type `[NSURL]` and because `[(null)]` does not match the type of `[NSURL]` you will get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPasteboard setURL:]: Argument is not an object of type NSURL [(null)]'
```

[UIPasteboard GitHub doc](https://github.com/BigZaphod/Chameleon/blob/master/UIKit/Classes/UIPasteboard.m)

[unsafe initializer used](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1460096-init)

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *shortenedURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login=%@&apikey=%@&longUrl=%@&format=txt", login, key, self.link.text]] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

is nil, so it's not a good idea to ignore the error.
Instead of that, do

```
NSError *loadingError = nil
NSString *shortenedURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login=%@&apikey=%@&longUrl=%@&format=txt", login, key, self.link.text]] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&loadingError]; 
if (!shortenURL) {
    NSLog(@"Error loading: %@", loadingError);
    return;
} else {
    NSLog(@"Success loading: %@", shortenedURL); 
}
```

You should get "Error loading: error message here", and debug the exact problem what happened.

Comment: The `if` statement should only check if `shortenedURL` is `nil`. It's possible `loadingError` could be non-nil even if there is no error.

Comment: After the correction of an API key my original code works, thanks.

Comment: it can work, but if you turn off internet for example, it will crash again.